# Why is there no WMI instance for Win32_Fan, when I do have a fan?

Tags: c++, wmi

I am using WMI to monitor certain hardware metrics, and specifically, I am using WMIExplorer.exe to find WMI classes and their instances(link to WMIExplorer.exe download: https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/wmi-explorer/). When I try to retrieve instances of the Win32_Fan class within the Root\cimv2 namespace, I get 0 instances. I am wondering why this is, since I do have a fan in my laptop. Do some fans/pieces of hardware not support retrieval through the WMI interface?

Note that I also tried the "Get-WmiObject -query "SELECT * FROM Win32_Fan" command in PowerShell to confirm there are no instances; there was no output from this command. I am simply wondering if there's any cause of an instance not showing up other than the hardware simply not being compatible with WMI. Or are there alternatives to finding fan speed without downloading third-party applications?(I want to get the fan speed within a personal C++ program).

Comment: If you look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-fan, there are error codes that can be returned. Have you looked in to the `ConfigManagerErrorCode` that is returned?

Comment: It would appear that either you don't have a WMI-compliant driver for your fan controller (typically part of an SMBus chip), or the chip does have a WMI-compliant driver but it only handles other features of the chip such as voltage monitoring and neglects the fan.  In either case, a driver update may help.

Comment: Most of the third-party applications you can download will be using a library that talks SMBus directly and not going through an abstraction such as WMI.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks; is there any third-party applications you would recommend?

Comment: I used to use SpeedFan, more recently OpenHardwareMonitor.  I'm pretty sure that the code for both is available and would show how, with the help of an I2C / SMBus bridge driver, you can read that data in your own code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Win32_Fan` instances are provided by `Windows\System32\wbem\cimwin32.dll`. If you disassemble it you will see that it reads SMBIOS data (specifically entries with type 27) to get fan device information. So having no such instances means your system manufacturer did not write fan device info into SMBIOS, which is part of ROM.